# Table or view not found when reading existing delta table

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake

I am new to Delalake. I was trying a simple example.

1. Create dataframe from a csv
2. Save it is as delta table
3. Read it again.

It works fine. I can see the files are created in the default spark-warehouse folder.

But Next time I just want to read the saved table. So I comment code for the first two septs and re-run the program I get

**Analysis Exception:Table or view not found**

```
 val transHistory = spark.
      read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferschema", true)
      .csv(InputPath + "trainHistory.csv");

    transHistory.write.format("delta").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("transactionshistory")

    val transHistoryTable = spark.read.format("delta").table("transactionshistory")
    transHistoryTable.show(10)
```

I am using delta lake 0.8.0, Spark 3.0, and scala 2.12.13

Comment: The format you will read is now delta not CSV. Try this val transHistory = spark.read.format("delta").option("header", "true").option("inferschema", true).load(InputPath + "trainHistory.csv")

Comment: What I am trying to do is reading a csv with regular spark api and saving it as delta table (transactionshistory) and read it back. Shouldn't it work?

BTW I tried your suggesion, it gives AnalysisException: `<InputPath>/RetailData/trainHistory.csv` is not a Delta table.

Comment: Yes, you need to change the csv filename with the delta table name. transactionshistory is your delta table name. You have to provide the full path while reading the delta table.

Comment: Why? When it stores the table in the warehouse it anyway chooses it own names. I can read the files with file path anyway. I want read it as a table.